# Cypress. check that at least one input in a group has a value

Tags: cypress

I have some inputs in the following div

```js
cy.get("div[data-test-letterinputcontainer='0']")
```

One of them have a value, but it is not known which. It could for example look like this

```html
<div data-test-letterinputcontainer="0">
    <input value="" type="text">
    <input value="" type="text">
    <input value="f" type="text">
    <input value="" type="text">
    <input value="" type="text">
    <input value="" type="text">
</div>
```

or this

```html
<div data-test-letterinputcontainer="0">
    <input value="g" type="text">
    <input value="" type="text">
    <input value="" type="text">
    <input value="" type="text">
    <input value="" type="text">
    <input value="" type="text">
</div>
```

How can I check that

- One `input` has a value
- The other `input`'s are empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
cy.get("div[data-test-letterinputcontainer='0'] input")
  .then(($ele) => {
    let flag = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < $ele.length; i++) {
      if (Cypress.$($ele[i]).val().toString().length) {
        //in case we found another input with a value.
        if (flag) {
          return false;
        }
        //first time finding a value for input.
        flag = true;
      }
    }
    return flag;
  })
  .should('eq', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply a filter to the inputs

```js
cy.get("div[data-test-letterinputcontainer='0']")
  .find('input')
  .should('have.length', 6)
  .filter('input[value=""]')   // how many empty?
  .should('have.length', 5)
```

Or conversely

```js
cy.get("div[data-test-letterinputcontainer='0']")
  .find('input')
  .should('have.length', 6)
  .filter('input[value!=""]')  // how many not empty?
  .should('have.length', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To check one input has a value

```js
cy.get("[data-test-letterinputcontainer=0]")
  .should("be.visible")
  .find("[value=f]")
  .its("length")
  .should("eq", 1);
```

To check rest of inputs do not have a value:

```js
cy.get("[data-test-letterinputcontainer=0]")
  .children()
  .its("length")
  .then((length) => {
    cy.get("[data-test-letterinputcontainer=0]")
      .find("[value='']")
      .its("length")
      .should("eq", length - 1);
  });
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/e2e/oneValue.md).